# Error to include dependency in Angularjs with Requirejs

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, requirejs

frontend part of service on Angularjs, now I try to configure it to work with Requirejs.

I need to resolve dependency in app.js

```
'application/services/P48Wallet'
```

In P48Wallet.js I need to resolve Http.js

```
define(['application/app', 'application/services/Http'], function(app) {
```

In Http.js, when I trying to return app.factory

```
return app.factory('Http', function($http, $q, $location, $rootScope) {
```

I receive an error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'factory' of undefined  Http.js**

```
console.log(app); // undefined
```

Whats wrong? Why app is undefined in Http.js

==================================================================================

**Project structure**

```
static()

    js()
        application()
            controllers()
                Main.js
            directives()
                ...
            filters()
                ...
            services()
                Http.js
                P48Wallet.js
            views()
                main.html
            app.js
            main.js
        libs()
            angular.min.js
            ....
```

==================================================================================

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script data-main="/static/js/application/main" src="/static/js/libs/require.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var server_url = '{$HTTP_STATIC_PATH}';
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="loader_cover" loader="{literal}{{showLoader}}{/literal}"><div class="loader_img"></div></div>
        <div class="page" ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

==================================================================================

**app.js**

```
define(
[
    'angularAMD',
    'angular-route',
    'angular-animate',
    'application/services/P48Wallet'
],
function (angularAMD) {

    var app = angular.module('Order', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider){

        $routeProvider
            .when('/',
                angularAMD.route({
                    templateUrl: 'static/js/application/views/main.html',
                    controller: 'application/controllers/Main',
                    resolve: {
                        deposits:
                            function(P48Wallet) {
                                return P48Wallet.getUserDeposits();
                            }
                    }
                })
            )

            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    });

    angularAMD.bootstrap(app);

    return app;
});
```

==================================================================================

**main.js**

```
require.config({

baseUrl: "static/js",

paths: {
    'angular':          'libs/angular.min',
    'angular-route':    'libs/angular-route.min',
    'angular-animate':  'libs/angular-animate.min',
    'angularAMD':       'libs/angularAMD.min'
},

shim: {
    'angularAMD': ['angular'],
    'angular-route': ['angular'],
    'angular-animate': ['angular']
},

deps: ['application/app']
});
```

==================================================================================

**Controller Main.js**

```
define(['application/app'], function (app) {

'use strict';
app.controller('Main', function ($rootScope, $location) {

    var Main = {};

    return $rootScope.Main = Main;
});
});
```

==================================================================================

**Services**

**1) Http.js**

```
'use strict';

define(['application/app'], function(app) {

return app.factory('Http', function($http, $q, $location, $rootScope) {

    return HTTP = {
        xxx: '/',
        xxx: false
    };
});
});
```

**2) P48Wallet.js**

```
'use strict';

define(['application/app', 'application/services/Http'], function(app) {

console.log(app); //undefined
return app.factory('P48Wallet', function(Http) {

// ...

    return this;
});
});
```

Comment: The code you show for `app.js` is has unbalanced brackets and parentheses. Perhaps you abbreviated your code from a bigger piece. A good way to do this and avoid pasting into your question code that is not balanced is to save your file under a different name and edit it with an editor that shows such problems. When you find there is no problem, *then* you can paste it into your question.

Comment: Fix unbalanced brackets and parentheses.
But I still can't understand, whats wrong, why I receive an error?

Comment: Can you include all the <script src=> tags from your index.html? I am thinking that you have an improper ordering of the angular library.

Comment: Update all index.html

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate of another question I just answered:

[angularjs + requirejs + dependency in resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561150/angularjs-requirejs-dependency-in-resolve/22570157#22570157)

In short:

1. You shouldn't be defining `resolve` property when using `angularAMD.route` and you should be defining `controller` and `controllerUrl`.  See documentation for [angularAMD.route](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD#on-demand-loading-of-controllers).
2. As your `Http.js` and `P48Wallet.js` is called after bootstrapping,  you should be defining those services using `app.register...` instead.

You really need to read up on [AngularJS' Providers](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/guide/providers) as `return HTTP = {...}` in your `Http.js` makes no sense.