# angularjs + requirejs + dependency in resolve

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

How I can correct inject dependency P48Wallet in resolve for $routeProvider?

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

define(
[
    'angularAMD',
    'angular-route',
    'angular-animate'
],
function (angularAMD) {

var app = angular.module('FilmOrder', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
            angularAMD.route({
                templateUrl: 'static/js/application/views/main.html',
                controller: 'application/controllers/Main',
                resolve: {
                     films:
                     require(['application/services/P48Wallet', function(P48Wallet) {
                         return P48Wallet.getUserData();
                     }])
                }
            })
        )

        .when('/success',
                angularAMD.route({
                templateUrl: 'static/js/application/views/success.html',
                controller: 'application/controllers/Success'
            })
        )

        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]);

    angularAMD.bootstrap(app);

    return app;
});
```

=========================================================

**P48Wallet.js**

```
'use strict';

define(['application/app', 'application/services/Http'], function(app) {

    return app.factory('P48Wallet', function(Http) {

        this.getUserData = function() {
            return Http.post('?action=get_data');
        };

        return this;
    });
});
```

=========================================================

I receive error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/unpr?p0=dProvider%20%3C-%20d
```

Answer (score 1):

2 problems that I can see:

1. `angularAMD.route` sets the `resolve` property so it is overwriting
   the `resolve` that you are setting up.
2. `return app.factory` expect an object to be return and not `this`

What you should be doing is define the `P48Wallet` as a factory/service and then add it to the dependency to your `Main` controller.  For example:

**application/services/P48Wallet.js**

EDIT: Adding feature to cache the returned data from POST per comment.

```
define(['application/app', 'application/services/Http'], function(app) {
    app.register.service('P48Wallet', function(Http, $q) {
        var priv_data;

        // Assuming that your Http works the same way as $http
        this.getUserData = function() {
            var d = $q.defer();

            if (priv_data) {
                // Return cached value
                d.resolve(priv_data);
            } else {
                Http.post('?action=get_data')
                .then(function (data) {
                    priv_data = data;
                    d.resolve(data);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    d.reject(error);
                });
            }
        };

        return d.promise;
    });
});
```

**application/controllers/Main.js**

```
define(['application/app', 'application/services/P48Wallet'], function (app) {
    app.register.controller("MainController", [
        '$scope', 'P48Wallet', function ($scope, P48Wallet) { ... }
    ]);
});
```

**application/app.js**

```
// Keeping everything the same except
angularAMD.route({
    templateUrl: 'static/js/application/views/main.html',
    controllerUrl: 'application/controllers/Main',
    controller: 'MainController'
})
```

Here is angularAMD's documentation on how to setup the route to lazy load controllers:

https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD#on-demand-loading-of-controllers

Comment: I need to resolve this variable (P48Wallet.getUserData()) before start my Controller, it can take 5 or 10 seconds. I cannot do this in controller. In controller i need concrete value not promise.

Comment: I am not sure how your `getUserData` works but one of the solution could be to cache the result so that subsequent calls are quicker.  In this case, you can call `. getUserData` during app initialisation via `app.run` and subsequent calls to it should be much quicker.

Comment: Resolve in app.js without requirejs fix it. I need to receive this data before I start work with controller.

Comment: You won't get it earlier than `app.run`.  Take a look at documentation for `.run`: [Module Loading & Dependencies](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

Comment: You advise me to create another module?

Comment: No... `.run` is a method of your ng-app module.  As per documentation: "used to kickstart the application".

Comment: I trying, but it's not help.

Comment: Setup a plunker and I will see what I can do.